# Linux USB to work as CD ROM in OS X

Tags: linux, macos, usb, drivers

I am working in driver development in Linux USB modules.
I have written a driver for USB and it is working as CD ROM in a Windows machine.

I made the first partiton as fat32

```
modprobe g_hidmass file=/dev/mmcblk0p1 cdrom=1 stall=0 removable=1
```

This works fine in Windows.

I made first partiton as HFS

```
modprobe g_hidmass file=/dev/mmcblk0p1 cdrom=1 stall=0 removable=1
```

But the same thing I applied with HFS in OS X I'm getting an error like this:

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer

In diskutil it is shown as a CD-rom but not reading the file system.

Please help me how can I overcome this error...
Your ideas are really helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Next time please edit your existing question rather than opening a new one. Thanks!